# How to initialize a Spring.net GenericApplicationContext after adding Object Definitions

Tags: c#, spring.net

Given a `GenericApplicationContext` and adding some `ObjectDefinitions` programatically. What do I need to do (others than calling `Refresh()`) to proper initialize the context?

The Problem is, that even with `IsLazyInit` set to `false` the `GetObject('beanId')` seems to bee extremly slow compared to `XmlApplicationContext` filled with the same `ObjectDefinitions` via XML Files.

Following code is from the constructor of my custom application context extending a `GenericApplicationContext`. Already tried the `ObjectDefinitionBuilder` without successfully solving the problem of `GetObject()` is very slow.

```
IObjectDefinitionFactory objectDefinitionFactory =  new DefaultObjectDefinitionFactory();
foreach (Tuple<Type, ComponentAttribute> type in typesWithComponentTypeAttribute) {
    //ObjectDefinitionBuilder builder = ObjectDefinitionBuilder.RootObjectDefinition(objectDefinitionFactory, type.Item1);
    //builder.SetAutowireMode(type.Item2.AutoWiringMode);
    //builder.SetSingleton(type.Item2.IsSingleton);
    //builder.SetLazyInit(false);
    //builder.SetDependencyCheck(DependencyCheckingMode.All);
    MutablePropertyValues mutableProperties = new MutablePropertyValues();
    IList<PropertyInfo> properties = type.Item1.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties) {
        IList<InjectTypeAttribute> injectByType = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InjectTypeAttribute), true).Cast<InjectTypeAttribute>().ToList();
        if (injectByType.Any()) {
            //builder.AddPropertyReference(propertyInfo.Name, typeToInjectFullName);
            //builder.AddDependsOn(typeToInjectFullName);
            string typeToInjectFullName = injectByType.First().TypeToInject.FullName;
            mutableProperties.Add(propertyInfo.Name, new RuntimeObjectReference(typeToInjectFullName));
        }
        IList<InjectNameAttribute> injectByName = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InjectNameAttribute), true).Cast<InjectNameAttribute>().ToList();
        if (injectByName.Any()) {
            //string nameToInject = injectByName.First().Name;
            //builder.AddPropertyReference(propertyInfo.Name, nameToInject);
            //builder.AddDependsOn(nameToInject);
        }
    }

    AbstractObjectDefinition objDef = objectDefinitionFactory.CreateObjectDefinition(type.Item1.FullName,null, AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
    objDef.AutowireMode = type.Item2.AutoWiringMode;
    objDef.IsLazyInit = false;
    objDef.IsSingleton = type.Item2.IsSingleton;
    objDef.PropertyValues = mutableProperties;

    //ObjectFactory.RegisterObjectDefinition(type.Item1.FullName, builder.ObjectDefinition);
    ObjectFactory.RegisterObjectDefinition(type.Item1.FullName, objDef);
}

Refresh();
```

Given an object structure for a view model with about 10 sub view models with about 2 services each (each with a DAO) takes about 12 seconds until completion. Compared to 3 seconds it takes to complete with a standart `XmlApplicationContext`. When hitting pause (in Visual Studio) during the 12 seconds of loading it always hangs at getting the object from the context.

```
IApplicationContext context = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
T vm = (T)context.GetObject(typeof(T).FullName, arguments);
return vm;
```

**Update 1 - Logfiles**

Logged the beginning of the creation of the mentioned view model.
1.) using the XML Context:

```
DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 – Returning context 'Spring.Context.Support.XmlApplicationContext' registered under name 'spring.root'.

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 –    GetObjectInternal: obtaining instance for name ProjectEditViewModel => canonical name ProjectEditViewModel

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 – Creating instance of Object 'ProjectEditViewModel' with merged definition [RootObjectDefinition : Class [Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.Windows.Project.ViewModels.ProjectEditViewModel]; Abstract = False; Parent = ; Scope = prototype; Singleton = False; LazyInit = False; Autowire = No; DependencyCheck = None; InitMethodName = ; DestroyMethodName = ; FactoryMethodName = ; FactoryObjectName = ; defined in = file [C:\Develop\vw_logiPIT\develop_mysql\TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf\bin\Release\Config\Spring.ViewModels.xml] line 525].

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 – Invoking IInstantiationAwareObjectPostProcessors before the instantiation of 'ProjectEditViewModel'.

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 – Configuring object using definition 'ProjectEditViewModel'

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 – Resolving reference from property 'ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel' in object 'ProjectEditViewModel' to object 'ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel'.

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 –       GetObjectInternal: obtaining instance for name ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel => canonical name ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 – Creating instance of Object 'ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel' with merged definition [RootObjectDefinition : Class [Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.UserControls.ActivityPlanTab.ViewModels.ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel]; Abstract = False; Parent = ; Scope = prototype; Singleton = False; LazyInit = False; Autowire = No; DependencyCheck = None; InitMethodName = ; DestroyMethodName = ; FactoryMethodName = ; FactoryObjectName = ; defined in = file [C:\Develop\vw_logiPIT\develop_mysql\TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf\bin\Release\Config\Spring.ViewModels.xml] line 967].

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 – Invoking IInstantiationAwareObjectPostProcessors before the instantiation of 'ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel'.

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 – Configuring object using definition 'ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel'

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 – Resolving reference from property 'ActivityPlanService' in object 'ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel' to object 'activityPlanService'.

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 –          GetObjectInternal: obtaining instance for name activityPlanService => canonical name activityPlanService

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 – Returning cached instance of singleton object 'activityPlanService'.

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 – Calling code asked for normal instance for name 'activityPlanService'.

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:27:56 –       GetObjectInternal: returning instance for objectname activityPlanService
```

2.) using the programatically added object definitions

```
DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 – Returning context 'Com.QueoFlow.Spring.Attributes.MixedApplicationContext' registered under name 'spring.root'.

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 –    GetObjectInternal: obtaining instance for name Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.Windows.Project.ViewModels.ProjectEditViewModel => canonical name Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.Windows.Project.ViewModels.ProjectEditViewModel

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 – Creating instance of Object 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.Windows.Project.ViewModels.ProjectEditViewModel' with merged definition [RootObjectDefinition : Class [Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.Windows.Project.ViewModels.ProjectEditViewModel]; Abstract = False; Parent = ; Scope = prototype; Singleton = False; LazyInit = False; Autowire = No; DependencyCheck = None; InitMethodName = ; DestroyMethodName = ; FactoryMethodName = ; FactoryObjectName = ].

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 – Invoking IInstantiationAwareObjectPostProcessors before the instantiation of 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.Windows.Project.ViewModels.ProjectEditViewModel'.

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 – Configuring object using definition 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.Windows.Project.ViewModels.ProjectEditViewModel'

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 – Resolving reference from property 'ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel' in object 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.Windows.Project.ViewModels.ProjectEditViewModel' to object 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.UserControls.ActivityPlanTab.ViewModels.ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel'.

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 –       GetObjectInternal: obtaining instance for name Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.UserControls.ActivityPlanTab.ViewModels.ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel => canonical name Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.UserControls.ActivityPlanTab.ViewModels.ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 – Creating instance of Object 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.UserControls.ActivityPlanTab.ViewModels.ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel' with merged definition [RootObjectDefinition : Class [Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.UserControls.ActivityPlanTab.ViewModels.ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel]; Abstract = False; Parent = ; Scope = prototype; Singleton = False; LazyInit = False; Autowire = No; DependencyCheck = None; InitMethodName = ; DestroyMethodName = ; FactoryMethodName = ; FactoryObjectName = ; defined in = file [C:\Develop\vw_logiPIT\branches_mysql\spring_attribute\TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf\bin\Release\Config\Spring.ViewModels.xml] line 911].

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 – Invoking IInstantiationAwareObjectPostProcessors before the instantiation of 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.UserControls.ActivityPlanTab.ViewModels.ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel'.

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 – Configuring object using definition 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.UserControls.ActivityPlanTab.ViewModels.ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel'

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 – Resolving reference from property 'ActivityPlanService' in object 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Wpf.Ui.UserControls.ActivityPlanTab.ViewModels.ActivityPlanTabControlViewModel' to object 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Services.Impl.ActivityPlanService'.

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 –          GetObjectInternal: obtaining instance for name Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Services.Impl.ActivityPlanService => canonical name Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Services.Impl.ActivityPlanService

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 – Creating instance of Object 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Services.Impl.ActivityPlanService' with merged definition [RootObjectDefinition : Class [Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Services.Impl.ActivityPlanService]; Abstract = False; Parent = ; Scope = prototype; Singleton = False; LazyInit = False; Autowire = No; DependencyCheck = None; InitMethodName = ; DestroyMethodName = ; FactoryMethodName = ; FactoryObjectName = ].

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 – Invoking IInstantiationAwareObjectPostProcessors before the instantiation of 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Services.Impl.ActivityPlanService'.

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 – Configuring object using definition 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Services.Impl.ActivityPlanService'

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 – Resolving reference from property 'ActivityPlanDao' in object 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Services.Impl.ActivityPlanService' to object 'Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Persistence.Impl.ActivityPlanDao'.

DEBUG2015-06-26 10:20:24 –             GetObjectInternal: obtaining instance for name Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Persistence.Impl.ActivityPlanDao => canonical name Com.QueoFlow.TrackingtoolLogistik.Persistence.Impl.ActivityPlanDao
```

The XMl Context simply returns the requested object whereas the generic context creates new instances down to the session factory.

Comment: Try to debug it with detailed common.logging output.
Compare the xml-Version with the slow-version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your problem, but if you don't want to wait when the context is initializing when you request an object you can call:

```
var context = (AbstractApplicationContext)ContextRegistry.GetContext();
context.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the Application Context should be done when your program first runs. Code will look like this:

```
private IApplicationContext context;

public void InitContext()
{
   // Configure Spring programmatically
   var ctx = new CodeConfigApplicationContext();
   ctx.ScanWithAssemblyFilter(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("My.Assemble.Name.Path"));
   ctx.Refresh();
   context = ctx;
}
```

After you have the Application context, you can ask for your objects like this:

```
IShapeDao circleDao = context.GetObject<IShapeDao>("circle");

IShapeDao rectangleDao = context.GetObject<IShapeDao>("rectangle");
```

Please go through this article if you need more help.

http://sovitpoudel.com.np/2017/03/11/notes-on-spring-net-dao-code-configuration/

Thanks.